# What is the default display property of a button in HTML?

Tags: html, css

If no display style is specified, what is it by default for a `<button>` element? Is it `block` or `inline-block`?

My Chrome is ambiguous. It says `block` and then `inline-block` so which one is it?

[image]

I'm almost certain it is inline-block, but I'd like to be sure. I couldn't find anything about it [in the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Inline block. See the behavior of the button in this snippet in Chrome.

```html
Is the button next to me? <button>Yes</button> Must be inline-block then...
```

Comment: Good experiment!

Comment: Why does it show up as "block" inside DevTools thought?

Comment: I'm not sure. Investigating the snippet in the iframe here I see inline-block in both the collapsed and expanded view for the display property in the Computed tab of the button styles. If that's true for you too when viewing this snippet but not your code, maybe there are some competing styles in your code. You can click on the "block" value and Chrome will show you where that is pulled from.